# VBS - schedule task + run in hidden

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, vbscript, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

I am trying to create a scheduled task and run in hidden mode (without console) my BAT file that does the processing... can someone help me? Here is one thing that I have tried...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jdqk.png)

Another thing I tried out of despair.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzEar.png)

What the bat file does is just send to the "server"(server - client) a message..
How do i change run as user to system..??

Comment: Pls post the code instead of the screenshot. And tell what happens when you use the script/batch file?

Comment: When adding the task on taskscheduler you need to change run as user to system, that way it will run on the background with no visible windows.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Properties for the task. On the General tab, select *Run whether user is logged on or not*.